# how to add multiple subtitles in Exo Player 2

Tags: android, subtitle, exoplayer

I want to show  subtitles  with ExoPlayer 2 . users can choose between languages (English,German, or Arabic) . Video links are HLS (.m3u8) and subtitles are .str files .

I  couldn't find any samples to do this.

is there any sample?

Comment: I have an answer that talks about video track selection, but the same logic applies to subtitle track selection. If you need more info, I can write out a more in depth answer here. Just let me know :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45835562/quality-selector-for-exoplayer-2/45844705#45844705

Comment: my subtitle are not in hls file . subtitle file are local . I really appreciate  if you answer the question @KyleVenn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45835562/quality-selector-for-exoplayer-2/45844705#45844705) I added as a comment to your original post will be how you'll build the UI around text track selection. Then to actually get the tracks to be added to your mp4 file (or whatever the format is), you'll want to use a `MergingMediaSource`. The simple version looks like so:

```
MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(videoUri, ...);
MediaSource subtitleSource = new SingleSampleMediaSource(subtitleUri, ...);
// Plays the video with the sideloaded subtitle.
MergingMediaSource mergedSource = new MergingMediaSource(videoSource, subtitleSource);
```

You can merge multiple subtitle tracks into the video source. Many different file formats are accepted.

I got that particular code sample from [this blog post](https://medium.com/google-exoplayer/exoplayer-2-x-mediasource-composition-6c285fcbca1f) - but I believe that same code is also in the ExoPlayer documentation. That code block combined with the sample code that I link to in my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45835562/quality-selector-for-exoplayer-2/45844705#45844705) should be enough to get you some subtitles.

Please let me know if that works for you.