# How to show HLS embedded captions on Exoplayer

Tags: android, vimeo, http-live-streaming, caption, exoplayer

how do I enable and also select different subtitles that are embedded in a Vimeo video in HLS format using Exoplayer, ExoMedia or another player?
In iOS this same video already presents the option of subtitles natively but in Android I cannot find means to implement it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works well!

```
TrackGroupArray trackGroups = mappedTrackInfo.getTrackGroups(rendererIndex);   

TrackSelectionArray currentTrackGroups = player.getCurrentTrackSelections();
TrackSelection currentTrackSelection = currentTrackGroups.get(rendererIndex);


    for (int groupIndex = 0; groupIndex < trackGroups.length; groupIndex++) {

        TrackGroup group = trackGroups.get(groupIndex);

        for (int trackIndex = 0; trackIndex < group.length; trackIndex++) {
            Format trackFormat = group.getFormat(trackIndex);


            if(currentTrackSelection!=null && currentTrackSelection.getSelectedFormat()==trackFormat){
                //THIS ONE IS SELECTED
            }




        }
    }
```

`rendererIndex` is `0` for Video, `1` for Audio and `2` for Subtitles/Text

Comment: If anyone is wondering how to get `mappedInfoTrack`

MappedTrackInfo mappedInfoTrack = trackSelector.getCurrentMappedTrackInfo()

Comment: I don't understand how this shows captions, and how this is the answer

Comment: Can anyone explain what part of this turns the captions on or off? How is this the answer?

Comment: `TrackGroupArray trackGroups = mappedTrackInfo.getTrackGroups(rendererIndex);   ` gives you all the available tracks, you can then use the loop to build trackGroups

Answer (score 5):

My answer here will look a lot like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45835562/quality-selector-for-exoplayer-2/45844705#45844705), so you might want to check that one out first.

ExoPlayer is the library you'll want for Android. It's a non- trivial task to get the subtitles to show, but the [demo app](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) for that library has all the code you'll need to get them working on an HLS video. More specifically the [`PlayerActivity`](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/demo/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/demo/PlayerActivity.java) class. You can go to HLS -> "Apple 16x9 basic stream" in the demo app and that video has a ton of subtitles (aka "text tracks").

Just to simplify their code so that it doesn't rely on the helper (and so you can see how it works *just* on closed captions) I've written/documented some of their code below.

```
private static class ClosedCaptionManager {

    ClosedCaptionManager(MappingTrackSelector mappingTrackSelector, SimpleExoPlayer player) {
        this.player = player;
        this.trackSelector = mappingTrackSelector;
    }

    SimpleExoPlayer player;
    MappingTrackSelector trackSelector;

    // These two could be fields OR passed around
    int textTrackIndex;
    TrackGroupArray trackGroups;

    ArrayList<Pair<Integer, Integer>> pairTrackList = new ArrayList<>();

    private boolean checkAndSetClosedCaptions() {
        // This is the body of the logic  for see if there are even video tracks
        // It also does some field setting
        MappedTrackInfo mappedTrackInfo = trackSelector.getCurrentMappedTrackInfo();
        if (mappedTrackInfo == null) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < mappedTrackInfo.length; i++) {
            trackGroups = mappedTrackInfo.getTrackGroups(i);
            if (trackGroups.length != 0) {
                switch (player.getRendererType(i)) {
                    case C.TRACK_TYPE_TEXT:
                        textTrackIndex = i;
                        return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void buildTrackList() {
        // This next part is actually about getting the list.
        // Below you'd be building up items in a list. This just does
        // views directly, but you could just have a list of track names (with indexes)
        for (int groupIndex = 0; groupIndex < trackGroups.length; groupIndex++) {
            TrackGroup group = trackGroups.get(groupIndex);
            for (int trackIndex = 0; trackIndex < group.length; trackIndex++) {
                if (trackIndex == 0) {
                    // Beginning of a new set, the demo app adds a divider
                }
                //CheckedTextView trackView = ...; // The TextView to show in the list
                // The below points to a util which extracts the quality from the TrackGroup
                //trackView.setText(DemoUtil.buildTrackName(group.getFormat(trackIndex)));
                Log.e("Thing", DemoUtil.buildTrackName(group.getFormat(trackIndex)));
                pairTrackList.add(new Pair<>(groupIndex, trackIndex));
            }
        }
    }

    private void onTrackViewClick(Pair<Integer, Integer> trackPair) {
        // Assuming you tagged the view with the groupIndex and trackIndex, you
        // can build your override with that info.
        Pair<Integer, Integer> tag = trackPair;
        int groupIndex = tag.first;
        int trackIndex = tag.second;
        // This is the override you'd use for something that isn't adaptive.
        // `override = new SelectionOverride(FIXED_FACTORY, groupIndex, trackIndex);`
        // Otherwise they call their helper for adaptives (HLS/DASH), which roughly does:
        int[] tracks = getTracksAdding(new MappingTrackSelector.SelectionOverride(
                        new FixedTrackSelection.Factory(), groupIndex, trackIndex),
                trackIndex
        );
        TrackSelection.Factory factory = tracks.length == 1
                ? new FixedTrackSelection.Factory()
                : new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(BANDWIDTH_METER);

        MappingTrackSelector.SelectionOverride override =
                new MappingTrackSelector.SelectionOverride(factory, groupIndex, tracks);

        // Then we actually set our override on the selector to switch the text track
        trackSelector.setSelectionOverride(textTrackIndex, trackGroups, override);
    }

    private static int[] getTracksAdding(MappingTrackSelector.SelectionOverride override, int addedTrack) {
        int[] tracks = override.tracks;
        tracks = Arrays.copyOf(tracks, tracks.length + 1);
        tracks[tracks.length - 1] = addedTrack;
        return tracks;
    }
}
```

Then if you post the following code into the end of their `initializePlayer()` method, you'll get an idea of how these pieces fit together.

```
    final ClosedCaptionManager closedCaptionManager = new ClosedCaptionManager(trackSelector, player);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            boolean hasTracks = closedCaptionManager.checkAndSetClosedCaptions();
            if (hasTracks) {
                closedCaptionManager.buildTrackList();
                closedCaptionManager.onTrackViewClick(closedCaptionManager.pairTrackList.get(4));
            }
        }
    }, 2000);
```

The code above is super sloppy, but it should hopefully at least get you started in the right direction. I wouldn't recommend using any piece of what's written - it should mostly be to get an idea of how the different pieces fit together. What they have in the demo app is a little better in that their code is very reusable for the different track selection types (since you can have video, audio, and text tracks).

Comment: Seems this code no longer works there is no method.  setSelectionOverride