# Exoplayer2 hls - choose quality

Tags: android, http-live-streaming, exoplayer2.x

I'm use the Exoplayer2 to play HLS videos and i want to let the user choose the quality of the video by himself.

i have this url for example : 
https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8

in this url we have 8 different resolutions, does somebody knows how can i choose one of them?

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45835562/quality-selector-for-exoplayer-2) might help you get started. If you need any further clarification, let me know.

Comment: Check the v2 release of the [demo application](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/demos/main/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/demo/TrackSelectionHelper.java).