# Manually add list of quality in exo player

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

I have 4 quality link for video I need to add a list of this quality in track selector in exo player manually or any method to do that

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ExoPlayer has built in controls to select the track quality if you want to do it manually - see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66473982/334402