# How to quality control functionality in Android Exoplayer?

Tags: android, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, exoplayer2.x

I want to play HLS video in exoplayer in my Android App. The following is the code-

```
    DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();

        //DefaultTrackSelector chooses tracks in the media item
        DefaultTrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(this);
        trackSelector.setParameters(trackSelector.buildUponParameters().setMaxVideoSizeSd());
        mPlayer = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).setTrackSelector(trackSelector).build();

        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "exoplayerapp"), bandwidthMeter);
        MediaSource mediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(url));

        mPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);

        playerView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
        playerView.requestFocus();
        playerView.setPlayer(mPlayer);
        mPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

It is working fine but I am unable to add quality control. The HSL stream has different quality formats like 249p, 360p, 480p but I am unable to select the track. Where should I change the code?

Comment: Check out the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70284559/6826629 .

Answer (score 2):

I've made a repo where you can find a quality selector I've made that could help you on HLS stream. I'm trying to keep it updated with the exoplayer version.

https://github.com/yoobi/exoplayer-kotlin/tree/master/qualityselector

---

**exo_player_control_view.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2016 The Android Open Source Project
     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at
          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    android:background="#CC000000"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_rew"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Rewind"/>

        <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_play"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Play"/>

        <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_pause"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Pause"/>

        <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_ffwd"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.FastForward"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/exo_quality_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/exo_quality"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_settings"
                style="@style/ExoMediaButton"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView android:id="@id/exo_position"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:textColor="#FFBEBEBE"/>

        <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DefaultTimeBar
            android:id="@id/exo_progress"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="26dp"/>

        <TextView android:id="@id/exo_duration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:textColor="#FFBEBEBE"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```kotlin
import android.app.Dialog
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.FrameLayout
import android.widget.ImageButton
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.C
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.MediaItem
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.DefaultTrackSelector
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.MappingTrackSelector
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.TrackSelectionDialogBuilder
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSource
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSourceFactory
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.MimeTypes
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util

const val HLS_STATIC_URL = "https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/MI201109210084_1/m3u8s/f08e80da-bf1d-4e3d-8899-f0f6155f6efa.m3u8"
const val STATE_RESUME_WINDOW = "resumeWindow"
const val STATE_RESUME_POSITION = "resumePosition"
const val STATE_PLAYER_FULLSCREEN = "playerFullscreen"
const val STATE_PLAYER_PLAYING = "playerOnPlay"
const val MAX_HEIGHT = 539
const val MAX_WIDTH = 959

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var exoPlayer: SimpleExoPlayer
    private lateinit var dataSourceFactory: DataSource.Factory
    private lateinit var trackSelector: DefaultTrackSelector
    private lateinit var playerView: PlayerView
    private lateinit var exoQuality: ImageButton

    private var currentWindow = 0
    private var playbackPosition: Long = 0
    private var isFullscreen = false
    private var isPlayerPlaying = true
    private var trackDialog: Dialog? = null
    private val mediaItem = MediaItem.Builder()
        .setUri(HLS_STATIC_URL)
        .setMimeType(MimeTypes.APPLICATION_M3U8)
        .build()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        playerView = findViewById(R.id.player_view)
        exoQuality = playerView.findViewById(R.id.exo_quality)

        dataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,
            Util.getUserAgent(this, "testapp"))

        exoQuality.setOnClickListener{
            if(trackDialog == null){
                initPopupQuality()
            }
            trackDialog?.show()
        }

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            currentWindow = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_RESUME_WINDOW)
            playbackPosition = savedInstanceState.getLong(STATE_RESUME_POSITION)
            isFullscreen = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(STATE_PLAYER_FULLSCREEN)
            isPlayerPlaying = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(STATE_PLAYER_PLAYING)
        }
    }

    private fun initPlayer(){

        trackSelector = DefaultTrackSelector(this)
        // When player is initialized it'll be played with a quality of MaxVideoSize to prevent loading in 1080p from the start
        trackSelector.setParameters(trackSelector.buildUponParameters().setMaxVideoSize(MAX_WIDTH,MAX_HEIGHT))
        exoPlayer = SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).setTrackSelector(trackSelector).build().apply {
            playWhenReady = isPlayerPlaying
            seekTo(currentWindow, playbackPosition)
            setMediaItem(mediaItem)
            prepare()
        }
        playerView.player = exoPlayer

        //Listener on player
        exoPlayer.addListener(object: Player.Listener{
            override fun onPlayerStateChanged(playWhenReady: Boolean, playbackState: Int) {
                if(playbackState == Player.STATE_READY){
                    exoQuality.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
            }
        })
    }

    private fun releasePlayer(){
        isPlayerPlaying = exoPlayer.playWhenReady
        playbackPosition = exoPlayer.currentPosition
        currentWindow = exoPlayer.currentWindowIndex
        exoPlayer.release()
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        outState.putInt(STATE_RESUME_WINDOW, exoPlayer.currentWindowIndex)
        outState.putLong(STATE_RESUME_POSITION, exoPlayer.currentPosition)
        outState.putBoolean(STATE_PLAYER_FULLSCREEN, isFullscreen)
        outState.putBoolean(STATE_PLAYER_PLAYING, isPlayerPlaying)
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        if (Util.SDK_INT > 23) {
            initPlayer()
            playerView.onResume()
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        if (Util.SDK_INT <= 23) {
            initPlayer()
            playerView.onResume()
        }
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        if (Util.SDK_INT <= 23) {
            playerView.onPause()
            releasePlayer()
        }
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        if (Util.SDK_INT > 23) {
            playerView.onPause()
            releasePlayer()
        }
    }

    // QUALITY SELECTOR

    private fun initPopupQuality() {
        val mappedTrackInfo = trackSelector.currentMappedTrackInfo
        var videoRenderer : Int? = null

        if(mappedTrackInfo == null) return else exoQuality.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        for(i in 0 until mappedTrackInfo.rendererCount){
            if(isVideoRenderer(mappedTrackInfo, i)){
                videoRenderer = i
            }
        }

        if(videoRenderer == null){
            exoQuality.visibility = View.GONE
            return
        }

        val trackSelectionDialogBuilder = TrackSelectionDialogBuilder(this, getString(R.string.qualitySelector), trackSelector, videoRenderer)
        trackSelectionDialogBuilder.setTrackNameProvider{
            // Override function getTrackName
            getString(R.string.exo_track_resolution_pixel, it.height)
        }
        trackDialog = trackSelectionDialogBuilder.build()
    }

    private fun isVideoRenderer(mappedTrackInfo: MappingTrackSelector.MappedTrackInfo, rendererIndex: Int): Boolean {
        val trackGroupArray = mappedTrackInfo.getTrackGroups(rendererIndex)
        if (trackGroupArray.length == 0) {
            return false
        }
        val trackType = mappedTrackInfo.getRendererType(rendererIndex)
        return C.TRACK_TYPE_VIDEO == trackType
    }

}
```