# control the quality of video manually in exoplayer

Tags: android, resolution, exoplayer

is there anyone who can help me to find a neat coding style in a simple way to set a control in my android app that user can change the quality of video manually. im using exoplayer
im looking for the answer for a while and the demo app is so complicated

Comment: you won't be able to control the quality unless the media source (remote URL for eg) has the capabilities to do so. you can explain more on what is your exact use case and someone can help!

Comment: @Bala Kirishna thanks for your reaction. i creat a video player by exoplayer library and now i want to add a button that user can change the quality of video like youtube option. i need a solution

Comment: This answer will hep you https://stackoverflow.com/a/70284559/6826629